# In Kubuntu, what `CTRL+;` (control + semicolon) shortkey is assigned to? I want to disable that

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

I was using Ubuntu before and assigned `ctrl+;` (control key + semicolon key) to some action in my editor and terminal. Recently, I switched to Kubuntu. This shortkey is assigned to something globally. I couldn't find it the the System Settings' Shortcut tab.

When I press it, it shows a little `e` at the cursor position.

Does anyone know what it is, and how can I disable it?

Some people suggest it belongs to `fcitx`'s clipboard but I don't have any `fcitx` package installed.

```
Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma 5.24.6
KDE Framework 5.92.0
```

[image: little e appears when I press ctrl + ;]

Comment: Probably ibus, to insert emoticons.

Comment: @vanadium Yes that was it! Thanks. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did. If in KDE you can change it another way than by running ibus-setup, then please inform me - I will then add it to the answer. Gnome Shell does not expose the setting afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shortcut key is assigned to ibus, and serves for inserting emoticons. You can change or disable the shortcut key in "Ibus preferences", which you can access with the command `ibus-setup`.